# AWS: Provide a limited and secure access to S3 object

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-s3, authorization

I want to upload a large (~40G) file on S3.

I would like to give access to **one specific person** to download this file (and **only** this file)

What is the best option? (regardless of whether I have to create/use an `IAM` account for that person or not) in terms of:

- authorization
- file encryption

How can I use end-to-end encryption (and assuming I have a secure channel with that person) pass her (after she downloads the file) the information needed for decryption?

Comment: How about generating a pre-signed URL for the person to download the file? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

Comment: Sounds good but if I understand correctly, if this `url` accidentally gets into the hands of someone else, he would be also available to download the file before the url expires; I would like to also have a form of auth for the actual file recipient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have a secure way to communicate, *and trust the other person,* then the simplest solution is to [generate a pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).

Whether you create a separate IAM user or not is up to you: creating a separate user will enable you to easily track their activity using [CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html).

The limitation of this solution is that anyone with the URL can access the object. So it's inappropriate if you don't have a secure way to provide the URL to the user, and also insecure if you can't trust the user not to share the URL.

In that latter case, however, any mechanism of supplying the file would be insecure: once the user has physical possession of the data she can do whatever she wants with it. Your only secure solution is providing some API that accesses data from the file in a form that cannot be used to reconstruct the file.

Regarding end-to-end encryption, you'd be providing an HTTPS URL, so would have encryption in transit. For encryption at rest (on the user's system) you would need to encrypt before uploading to S3.